# top-down recursive descent method to implement a parser in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I need to rewrite the grammar in EBNF. Use the top-down recursive descent method to implement a parser
(i.e. tdrd parser.py ) in python3 for the EBNF grammar. The input data file name is given from
the command line. Assume that there is a space character between two terminals
(e.g. a a a c c b ) in the data file.

Here is grammar:

```
<S> -> <A> c c <B> | <B> d d <A>
<A> -> a <A> | a
<B> -> b <B> | b
```

Here is the code:

```
import sys


def lexan():
    global mitr

    try:
        return next(mitr)
    except StopIteration:
        return ''


def match(ch):
    global lookahead

    if ch == lookahead:
        lookahead = lexan()
    else:
        print("Syntax Error")
        exit()


def S(): 
    #<S> -> <A> c c <B> | <B> d d <A>
    global lookahead
    if lookahead == 'a':
        A()
        #match('c')
        C()
    elif lookahead == 'b':
        B()
        #match('c')
        C()
    else:
        print("Syntax Error")
        exit()


def A():
    # <A> -> a <A> | a
    global lookahead
    match('a')
    if lookahead == 'a':
        A()


def B():  # <B> -> b <B> | b

    global lookahead
    match('b')
    if lookahead == 'b':
        B()


def C():

    global lookahead
    match('c')
    if lookahead == 'c':
        C()

file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
wlist = file.read().split()
mitr = iter(wlist)

lookahead = lexan()
S()
if lookahead == '':
    print("Pass")
else:
    print("Syntax Error")
    exit()
```

Whenever I run it: python3 tdrd_parser.py data.txt if I remove b from the file - I get a "Pass". Otherwise - Syntax Error.

Could you please assist?

Comment: Where did `C` come from? There's no such non-terminal in the grammar. Also, your interpretation in `S()` of the two top-level productions seems to stop in the middle of the right-hand side.

Comment: Well, so I am not really good at the EBNF grammar - but I thought since we have c c between A and B we have to include C? Also, in addition, I am not sure why it gets stuck? Do I need to include more if statements?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, S() should look like that:def s():
if lookahead == 'a':
A()
match('c')
match('d')
B()
elif lookahead == 'b':
match('d')
match('c')
A()
else:
print ("Syntax error")
exit() @rici

Comment: Close. According to your grammar, `A(); match('c'); match('c'); B();` and `B(); match('d'); match('d'); A();`. But that's not what you have, is it? The production which starts `A()` never calls `B()`, so it shouldn't be a surprise that a `b` at the end of the input isn't recognised.

Comment: @rici makes sense now! Thanks, man! Will try to implement it today! :)